# Receiving Error C2670 in Visual Studios 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've searched throughout my entire code, and there aren't any other issues except for this section. The semicolon at the end of the forward-slashed line is the issue. Is there something I'm missing? Full error message below.

source\repos\Square Matrix\SquareMatrix.cpp(108,27): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ';', expected '{'

```
#pragma once
#include <stdexcept>
#include "SquareMatrix.h"

template<typename T>
class SquareMatrix
{
    private:
        size_t _size;  //will be the size of the array. size_t makes sure i only use nonnegative integers for the size
        T **_ptr;
public:
    SquareMatrix(); //zero parameter constructor
    SquareMatrix(const SquareMatrix& rhs); //copy constructor  
    ~SquareMatrix(); //destructor
    SquareMatrix(SquareMatrix&& rhs); //Move Constructor
    SquareMatrix& operator=(const SquareMatrix& rhs); //Copy assignment Operator
    SquareMatrix& operator=(SquareMatrix&& rhs);  //Move Assignment Operator 
    void resize(size_t new_size);
    T& at(int row, int column);
    size_t size() const;
};

template<typename T>
void SquareMatrix<T>::resize(size_t new_size)
{
std::cout << "Input size of the new matrix: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> new_size;

for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        delete[] _ptr[i];
    }
if (_ptr != nullptr)
    delete[] _ptr;

if (new_size != _size)
    {
        _ptr = new T * [new_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
        {
            // _ptr[i] = T *[new_size]; //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What headers are you including? Do they have any error? Could you include them here?

Comment: included headers as requested. This is the only error I haven't been able to figure out and I'm thinking its something really small that I can't see because I've been working at this for a bit.

Comment: What are you trying to do on that line? Think about that, and what might be missing.

Comment: Where is the declaration for `_ptr`, since it is involved in the error?

Comment: Once you get this compiling, `if (new_size != _size)` is going to cause trouble, positioned where it is.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this is a matrix class. The declaration for _ptr is in the private section of that class.

Comment: Now that we know *were* it is located, what's the type of `_ptr`?  You could paste the class declaration into your question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The whole file is like 140 lines of code. Am i allowed to do that?

Comment: @PaulSanders ok, i think i can see where i messed up. I'll give it a go after i figure this out. Thanks man!

Comment: @Learning `_ptr[i]` is a `T*`. What are you trying to set it to on that line?

Comment: @dxiv thanks man. I realize that i was allocating even more memory to _ptr[i]. And that I should remove the asterisk between T and [new_size]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue might be in the declaration of your class `SquareMatrix`. You have not posted it so I cant tell for sure but I tested your method implementation with a dummy class and I don't get any errors in compilation.

Make sure that your class declaration and method declaration have this syntax:

```cpp
template<class T>
class SquareMatrix {
        T a, b;
    public:
        void resize(size_t new_size);
};
```

You can review the section on Class Templates to get some examples and a more through explanation.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the declaration of my class for visual clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.